# How to Importrange + CountIf on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, import, count, match, google-query-language

I need to import information from another google sheet, COUNTIF that information under the criteria of one column saying "VIL" and another column saying "Pass"

I am using variations of the below:
=countifs((IMPORTRANGE(E65, "Sheet1!A2:H200")),$E$2:$E$30,"*Passed*")

Where I am trying to have it display the count of boxes that have "Passed" from the other google sheet in E65. I am only getting error messages.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster I’m having a grammar crisis, should maybe be may be maybe?

Comment: @CodeCamper https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12849/what-is-the-difference-between-maybe-and-may-be :)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this first to connect your sheets:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(E65; "Sheet1!A2")
```

then try:

```
=ROWS(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(E65; "Sheet1!A2:H200")}; 
 "where Col5 = 'Pass' and Col1 = 'VIL'"; ))
```

change `Col1` to where the `VIL` is